# How can I convert some columns of a pandas dataframe to categorical?

Tags: python, pandas

This is my code:

```
l1 = list(train)
for i in (0,len(l1)):
    if train[l1[i]].dtypes == object:
        train[l1[i]] = pd.Categorical(train[l1[i]])

train.info(verbose=True)
```

But this just makes the first variable change and nothing else. The rest of the 62 object variables aren't converted to object.

How do you do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all object columns by [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html), convert to dict and pass to [`DataFrame.astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
train = train.astype(dict.fromkeys(train.select_dtypes('object').columns, 'category'))
```